# Arcpy Result object - status Waiting, Cancelling, etc?

Tags: arcpy, result-object

This is a question similar to [Using ArcPy Result object associated with Currently Running Script](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16439/arcpy-result-object-associated-with-currently-running-script).

I'm curious about how [result objects](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/classes/result.htm) in arcpy can have certain statuses that indicate a geoprocess in process. Statuses such as **Submitted**, **Waiting**, **Executing**, **Cancelling**, and **Deleting**. As I understand them, result objects can't be accessed until a geoprocess has completed. Is there a way to access such information mid-process with the result object?

Comment: ArcGIS Server jobs can have those statuses.

Comment: This help page shows the use of a while loop to pause your script till the status changes. See example 2. http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/classes/result.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by @Vince:

> ArcGIS Server jobs can have those statuses.

and by @dslamb:

> This help page shows the use of a while loop to pause your script till
>   the status changes. See example 2.
>   http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/classes/result.htm